# C++ Replace strings function does not work if the sentence to replace has the "+" sign

Tags: c++

I use this function to replace words and phrases in a file and it works great

Just one problem
If the sentence I want to replace has the '+' sign as part of the sentence then the function does not replace anything in this sentence and it remains the same and everything because of this plus sign

```
int Replace(std::string Rfrom, std::string Rto) {

auto from = "Replace+txt", to = "sentence";
for (auto filename : { "A.txt", "B.txt" }) {
    ifstream infile{ filename };
    string content{ ist {infile}, ist{} };
    infile.close();
    ofstream outfile{ filename };
    regex_replace(ost{ outfile }, begin(content), end(content), regex{ from }, to);
}
return 0;
}
```

I also tried to change the + sign to String and it did not work either

```
char c = '+';
std::string s;
s.push_back(c);
auto from = "Replace"+s+"txt", to = "sentence";
```

Update to my question
As suggested here "Replace\+text" works great. add "\" to the "+".

But the problem is that I have a function that automatically finds the sentences I want to replace. Basically, the function finds all the sentences that start with the "//" sign because what I want is to automatically delete all the notes from the file of my software. So I also need a function that automatically adds the "\" to any "+" found in sentences. Do you have an idea how to do this please?

```
int countSub(const std::string& str, const std::string& sub)
{
if (sub.length() == 0) return 0;
int count = 0;
for (size_t offset = str.find(sub); offset != std::string::npos;
    offset = str.find(sub, offset + sub.length()))
{
    ++count;
}
return count;
}

int line(std::string mfile) {

string fline;
std::string lineFix;
int i = 0;
ifstream myfile(mfile);

if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
    getline(myfile, fline);     
    if (countSub(fline, "//") != 0) {
 cout << "line [" << ++i << "]:" << fline << "  | Successfully deleted" << endl;
        Replace(fline, " ");
        }

        }
     }
        return 0;
     }
```

Many thanks

Comment: `+` is a metacharacter in regexps, you know that, don't you?

Comment: ... So try `"Replace\\+txt"`

Comment: The plus sign indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on, but not "ac". 
You need to "escape" that one.

Comment: thanks for the answers "Replace\\+txt" does not work. Do you have any more suggestions because I'm lost!

Answer (score 4):

The character `'+'` has special meaning in a regular expression.  It means "match the previous thing one or more times", so the pattern `"Replace+txt"` will match `"Replacetxt"` or `"Replaceetxt"` or `"Replaceeetxt"`, etc.

If you want to match a literal `'+'` character, you need to escape it in your pattern: `"Replace\\+txt"`.

Comment: "Replace\\+txt" does not work. Do you have any more suggestions

Comment: [It works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dda8a468c7be896).  Without knowing more about what your input looks like I couldn't tell you why things aren't working in your case.

Comment: I'm so sorry, you're right it works, it did not work because I put "Replace\\+txt" in the test file too. When actually in the test file I had to put "Replace+txt". Thank you very much.

Comment: But the problem is that I have a function that automatically finds the sentences I want to replace. Basically, the function finds all the sentences that start with the "//" sign because what I want is to automatically delete all the notes from the file of my software. So I also need a function that automatically adds the "\\" to any "+" found in sentences. Do you have an idea how to do this please?

Comment: I updated the question with the code of the function I specified. Thank you very much.